# Accessing matplotlib colorbar title in SHAP Dependence Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, shap

I want to change the title of the colorbar in the SHAP dependence plot.
A dependence plot is created with:

```
shap.dependence_plot("Age", shap_values, X, interaction_index="Education-Num", show=False)
```

The plot can be extracted with

```
fig, ax = plt.gcf(), plt.gca()
```

This allows for changes e.g. to the x-limits.

```
plt.xlim(0,10)
```

When trying to access the colorbar title with

```
clb = plt.colorbar()
clb.ax.set_title('New Label',fontsize=8)
```

a secondary colorbar is created, in addition to the existing one.
How can the existing colorbar title be overwritten, without creating a new one?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually, matplotlib creates a new `ax` to place its colorbar.  You can access it as the last element in `fig.axes`. E.g. `fig.axes[-1].set_title('My colorbar title')`

Comment: Brilliant! As it turns out,  SHAP saves the colorbar title in the ylabel, i.e., the answer is:
`fig.axes[-1].set_ylabel('My colorbar title')`
Thanks!